# Access or modify petite-vue data outside app

Tags: vue.js, petite-vue

I'm using petite-vue as I need to do very basic UI updates in a webpage and have been drawn to its filesize and simplicity. I'd like to control the UI's state of visible / invisible DOM elements and class names and styles of various elements.

I have multiple JavaScript files in my app, I'd like to be able to make these changes from any of them.

In Vue JS it was possible to do things like this...

```
const vueApp = new Vue({ el: "#vue-app", data(){
  return { count: 1}
}})

setTimeout(() => { vueApp.count = 2 }, 1000)
```

I'm trying the same with Petite Vue but it does nothing.

```
// Petite Vue
const petiteVueApp = PetiteVue.createApp({
  count: 0,
}).mount("#petite-vue");

setTimeout(() => { petiteVueApp.count = 2 }, 1000);
```

Logging the app gives just a directive and mount attribute, I can't find the `count` (nb if you log the above app it will show the count, because of that line `petiteVueApp.count = 2`, that isn't the data)

Demo:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/YzemBVB

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example which does exactly this in the docs which I overlooked.

https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#global-state-management

It requires an import of the @vue/reactivity which can be imported from the petite-vue bundle.

```
import { createApp, reactive } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'

setTimeout(() => { vueApp.count = 2 }, 1000)

const store = reactive({
  count: 0,
  inc() {
    this.count++
  }
})

createApp({
  store
}).mount("#petite-vue")

setTimeout(() => { store.count = 2 }, 1000);
```

Updated working example:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/ExEYYXQ

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue/blob/main/src/app.ts#L82) it seems that we would want it to `return ctx.scope` instead of `return this`.

Your workaround seems like the best choice if using petite-vue as given, or you could fork petite-vue and change that one line (I haven't tested this).

Comment: Oh my goodness your article on hexagons is one of my all time favourite web pages in the world! That, and 2D visibility. I am humbled to have you visit my question :joy:

Comment: Thank you! The hexagon page is currently implemented in Vue v2, and I was looking at this question because I am considering switching the page to Petite Vue. :-) 

Maybe instead of `return ctx.scope` it would be better to put the scope inside of `this` so that we could `return this` but also have access to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I did fork petitevue to ppvue..but apparently not as simple as returning ctx.scope

This did the trick for me though.

```js
        var vz = {
            count: 0,
            a1: "foo",
            inc: function () {
                this.count++
            }
        }

        var state = ppvue.createApp(vz).mount();
        
        
        setTimeout(() => { vz.inc() }, 3000);
```